# T_SL Error, Shoppying Basket System

Tags: php

When running the code shown below I get this error: ( ! )

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in D:\Program Files\wamp\www\Fatz\Fatz Shopping Cart.php on line 13
```

Code:

```
<?php
$_Session['Basket'] = '';

$User = 'Username';
$Pass = 'Password';
$Database = 'database';

mysql_connect(localhost, $User, $Pass);
@mysql_select_db($Database) or die('Unable to select database');

$sql = <<<MySQL_Query; <!-- Error Line-->

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test
{
    ItemID int(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    Title varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
    Price decimal(3,2) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (ItemID)
} MySQL_Query;

mysql_query($sql);

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1, 'What are we selling!', '10.00');

function ShoppingBaskItems()
{
    $basket = $_Session['Basket'];
    If(!isset($basket) || null($basket)) return '0 Items';
    $Items = explode(',', $basket);
    $Count = (count($Items) > 1) ? 'Count': '';
    return '<p><a href="Basket.php">'.count($Items).' items'.$Count.' </a></p>';
}

echo ShoppingBaskItems(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`< !-- ... -->` are the HTML comment tags. In php you have to use `//` , `#` or `/** */`.

EDIT:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test
{
ItemID int(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
Title varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
Price decimal(3,2) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (ItemID)
}";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Mybad but I added that for you so my problem still persists

Comment: Updated the post. And remove your insert query or place it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

When using [HEREDOCs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), the token needs to be on a line by itself, also do *not* put a semicolon after the token on the `$sql =` line.

```
$sql = <<<MySQL_Query

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test
{
    ItemID int(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    Title varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
    Price decimal(3,2) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (ItemID)
}
MySQL_Query;
```